# Regulations concerning non-commercial lithium ion battery transportation

Tags: united-states, california, transportation, shipping

With the proliferation of lithium ion-batteries for small-scale energy storage projects, non-commercial transportation of significantly large batteries (in the few kWh range, much larger than the few hundred Wh limits currently set for non-regulated batteries) will become much more common. What regulations pertain to this type of non-commercial transport in the U.S.? How does this change once the batteries are installed in a trailer, RV, boat, or other transportable vehicle?

My specific situation is that a repair shop is requiring HAZMAT certification for whoever picks up a replaced Tesla battery pack that I wish to (personally) transport elsewhere. Is this a governmental regulation in general if, say, I was to (personally) transport the pack or its components in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Transporting Lithium Batteries](https://www.phmsa.dot.gov/lithiumbatteries)

> Lithium batteries are regulated as a hazardous material under the U.S. Department of Transportation's (DOT's) Hazardous Materials Regulations ([HMR; 49 C.F.R., Parts 171-180](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CFR-2012-title49-vol2/xml/CFR-2012-title49-vol2-subtitleB-chapI-subchapC.xml)). The HMR apply to any material DOT determines is capable of posing an unreasonable risk to health, safety, and property **when transported in commerce**. Lithium batteries must conform to all applicable HMR requirements when offered for transportation or transported by air, highway, rail, or water.

**Is this a governmental regulation in general if, say, I was to (personally) transport the pack or its components in the future?**

The HMR is a weighty tome so there may be more information to add to properly answer the question, but in the meantime this appears relevant:

> (d) *Functions not subject to the requirements of the HMR*. The following are examples of activities to which the HMR **do not apply**:
>
> (6) Transportation of a hazardous material by an individual for non-commercial purposes in a private motor vehicle, including a leased or rented motor vehicle.

*UPDATE: I have reviewed the HMR and there does not appear to be anything else of direct relevance to the question*